# Rich and poor separated, and a romance

Tags: story-identification, books

About a year ago I read a book, I don’t know if the book was new then, but it might help if you know that is is not brand new.

The premise of the story is that the rich people now live in the tops of the buildings of the city, with bridges in between the buildings so that they never have to go to the ground and see all the suffering of the poor people. The ground area is called ‘the deeps’ or ‘the depths’ I don’t really remember, and it is where all the poor people live.

I think the protagonist's name is Ariana or something similar, and the book begins with her waking up with no memories. She is rich and part of one of the most powerful families in the city. Her mom tells her that she overdosed on a drug and it took away her memories. Her mom also tells her that she is going to be married to a boy (that is supposedly the love of her life but she doesn’t remember). The boy is from the other most powerful family in the city and their union is going to end the feud between the two families.

But to Ariana (I’m just going to pretend that’s her name) something isn’t right. She goes down into the deeps and meets a person named Daniel (I think) and the talk for a long time.

I don’t remember how but eventually she regains her memories and figured out that Daniel was the love of her life all along. I think they run away together at the end.

Comment: Is this a short story? I think I remember a similar one in a Galaxy magazine or something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [Mystic City](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13411245-mystic-city) by Theo Lawrence.

- Aria not Ariana but otherwise exactly as described in the question.

  > Aria Rose, youngest scion of one of Mystic City's two ruling rival
  >   families, finds herself betrothed to Thomas Foster, the son of her
  >   parents' sworn enemies. The union of the two will end the
  >   generations-long political feud - and unite all those living in the
  >   Aeries, the privileged upper reaches of the city, against the banished
  >   mystics who dwell below in the Depths.
  >
  > But Aria doesn't remember falling in love with Thomas; in fact, she
  >   wakes one day with huge gaps in her memory. And she can't conceive why
  >   her parents would have agreed to unite with the Fosters in the first
  >   place.
  >
  > Only when Aria meets Hunter, a gorgeous rebel mystic from the Depths,
  >   does she start to have glimmers of recollection - and to understand
  >   that he holds the key to unlocking her past. The choices she makes can
  >   save or doom the city - including herself.
- The poor live in The Depths and the rich live in The Aeries

  > *Most live far away from us, among the poor, in the lower level of the
  >   city, known as the Depths—a place too terrible and too dangerous for
  >   anyone from the Aeries to even visit. The mystics in the Aeries are
  >   servants or waiters or government workers who don’t care about
  >   revolution or power. All they care about is earning enough to survive.*
- There's no Daniel but there is a character called Davida who briefly disguises herself as the male love-interest, Hunter.

[image]